# Java - WatchService another machine folder

Tags: java, path, watchservice

Is there a way to use watch for file change in another machine using IP address?

Currently my code are:

```
WatchService ws = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

`Path d = FileSystem.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.dir"),"");
 WatchKey wk  = dir.register(ws, .... , ...);`

Anyway to change the Path variable to point to a folder in another IP. I.e 192.168.123.123?

Comment: How do you access that folder on another machine from your machine (outside Java)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @seelenvirtuose, maybe a share folder? i do not want to transfer it out. I just want to "observe" for change and show the changes.

Comment: @stefan, the jar I am creating will be on my own local machine, i wan to observe another file in another machine from the  same network.

Comment: @chj What I wanted to tell you: If this is a shared folder, you usually access it with `//<name-or-ip>/<sharing-name>/<subfolders>`. This is a path that also can be used in Java.

Comment: Maybe you want to try a look at [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcifsfilesystem/); not sure however whether it supports creating a `WatchService`... (edit: no it doesn't; in fact it supports pretty much nothing, forget it)

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but why? You will have to sharethe resources from the other computer anyway, through network sharing or by using a client on the other computer.

Comment: @stefan, just trying to test some concept. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the path using IP as written in comments above. But be careful since monitoring remote system is not supposed to be supported by Watch Service.

From [WatchService javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

> If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on remote systems be detected.